# Visual Studio 2013 Disassembly Reference

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, disassembly

I'm sorry if I am just being blind and can't see it, but does anyone know of a good reference page for the Visual Studio 2013 disassembly instruction set? I understand a lot of the basic/general instructions just fine, but occasionally I come across something like `rep stos    dword ptr es:[edi]` and need a little more information to understand it. I usually find an explanation for the instruction I am looking up, but I'm just wondering if there is a reference page that has a list of all the instructions and variable names that MS uses in their VS 2013 disassembly. I have looked through forums and MSDN for the last 15 minutes and cannot seem to find a page like this, nor anyone mentioning/asking for a page like this so that is why I am asking here.

Comment: Microsoft did not invent that, Intel did.  Go to intel.com, search for "processor manuals", get volume 2.